# AnythingSlider duplicated static links issue

Tags: jquery, anythingslider

i'm encountering an issue with static links of an AnythingSlider plugin.

I want to replicate a specific static link, connected to the third panel of the slider, one time outside the slider and other times inside it.

the js code is:

```
jQuery("#jump3").click(function () {
jQuery("#slider1").anythingslider(3);
});
```

this worked perfectly till I had only one static link:

```
<a href="#" id="jump3"...>
```

but now I want to replicate this anchor even inside the slider.

If I change from id to class doesn't work in IE6.
The biggest issue, on the other end, still using ids, is that only the static link outside slider works. The inside one not..the third panel doesn't slide if clicking on it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/pbbYP/468/)):

```
jQuery(".jump3").click(function () {
  jQuery("#slider1").anythingSlider(3);
});
```

The "S" in Slider needs to be capitalized.